# Making site fit to different resolutions

Tags: html, web, fullscreen

I need some CSS code to make my site fit the whole screen in different resolutions, however if screen goes too small, stop resizing and become scrollable. I've tried using a div covering the whole screen, and then setting width and height to 100%, with min-width set to 800px and min-height set to 600px, but its not working. Any ideas?

PS: Solution must be pure HTML/CSS, JavaScript is not possible for me now.

Comment: Have look on http://aozora.github.io/bootmetro/ dig in css and you find how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/6CpbZ/

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

min-width: 500px;
min-height: 500px;
```

The concept is making the width or height or both 100% and then defining a min-width or min-height.